# Converting long numbers to date in R

Tags: r, date

I have an excel file which I am trying to read in R using read_excel function. The dates field in my data are pivoted up i.e. they are as columns.  See screenshot below

[image]

The problem is when R reads the data file it converts the date fields columns to something like below.

[image]

Now, I have extracted the dates in a vector vDates and trying to convert them back to dates using below code , but it gives me error. [image]

Please let me know what is it that I am missing here!.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Please don't use images to share code and error messages. This makes it much harder for others to find questions via text search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your screen number `43102` is `"2018-01-04"`, but real date for it is `"2018-01-02"`.
I use this one:

```
as.Date(as.numeric(vdates), origin = "1899-12-30")
[1] "2018-01-01" "2018-02-01" "2018-03-01"
```